# Why is RSAParameters Modulus not equal product of P and Q?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa

The values of P and Q do not match value of the Modulus of the .Net RSAParameters.
According to RSA algorithm and MSDN documentation it should be: P * Q = Modulus

I generated a 512bit RSA keypair and exported it to XML by invoking:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
rsa.ToXmlString(true);
```

This gave me the following XML:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
  <Modulus>rcLI1XTfmXtX05zq67d1wujnUvevBu8dZ5Q5uBUi2mKndH1FZLYCKrjFaDTB/mXW1l5C74YycVLS6msY2NNJYw==</Modulus>
  <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
  <P>1dwGkK5POlcGCjQ96Se5NSPu/hCm8F5EYwyqRpLVzgk=</P>
  <Q>0AAEMHBj7CP2XHfCG/RzGldw1GdsW13rTo3uEE9Dtws=</Q>
  <DP>PO4jMLV4/TYuElowCW235twGC3zTE0jIUzAYk2LiZ4E=</DP>
  <DQ>ELJ/o5fSHanBZCjk9zOHbezpDNQEmc0PT64LF1oVmIM=</DQ>
  <InverseQ>NyCDwTra3LiUin05ZCGkdKLwReFC9L8Zf01ZfYabSfQ=</InverseQ>
  <D>EWwFTPmx7aajULFcEJRNd2R4xSXWY8CX1ynSe7WK0BCH42wf/REOS9l8Oiyjf587BhGa3y8jGKhUD7fXANDxcQ==</D>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Now I successfully wrote a litte test programm to encrypt, decrypt, sign and verify data.

At the end I added a little test code:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(512);
rsa.FromXmlString(key); // key = string with XML above

RSAParameters param = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(param.P);
BigInteger q = new BigInteger(param.Q);
BigInteger n = new BigInteger(param.Modulus);
BigInteger myN = BigInteger.Multiply(p, q);
Console.WriteLine("n   = " + n.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("myN = " + myN.ToString());
```

Which gave we the following output:

```
n   = 5200154866521200075264779234483365112866265806746380532891861717388028374942014660490111623133775661411009378522295439774347383363048751390839618325234349

myN = 23508802329434377088477386089844302414021121047189424894399694701810500376591071843028984420422297770783276119852460021668188142735325512873796040092944
```

Why does multiplying P and Q not equal the Modulus?

I already checked a lot of things like endian, encoding, BigInteger class, successfully encrypted, decrypted, signed, verified with the above XML keys but cannot find any explanation why P and Q multiplied is not equaling the Modulus...

Can anybody help me explain why P*Q is not the Modulus ?

All values in readable format:

```
Modulus  = 5200154866521200075264779234483365112866265806746380532891861717388028374942014660490111623133775661411009378522295439774347383363048751390839618325234349
Exponent = 65537
P  = 4436260148159638728185416185189716006279182659244174640493183003717504785621
Q  = 5299238895894527538601438806093945941831432623367272568173893997325464109264
DP = -57260184070162652127728137041376572684067529466727954512100856352006444159428
DQ = -56270397953566513533764063103154348713259844205844432469862161942601135050224
InverseQ = -5297700950752995201824767053303055736360972826004414985336436365496709603273
D = 5967761894604968266284398550464653556930604493620355473531132912985865955601309375321441883258487907574824598936524238049397825498463180877735939967118353
```

**UPDATE**:

According to the answer I wrote a little extension method for the .Net BigInteger class to work correctly with the RSAParameters:

```
public static class BigIntegerExtension
{
    public static BigInteger FromBase64(this BigInteger i, string base64)
    {
        byte[] p = Convert.FromBase64String(base64).Reverse().ToArray();
        if (p[p.Length - 1] > 127)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref p, p.Length + 1);
            p[p.Length - 1] = 0;
        }
       return new BigInteger(p);
    }

    public static BigInteger FromBigEndian(this BigInteger i, byte[] p)
    {
        p = p.Reverse().ToArray();
        if (p[p.Length - 1] > 127)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref p, p.Length + 1);
            p[p.Length - 1] = 0;
        }
        return new BigInteger(p);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
BigInteger modulus1 = new BigInteger().FromBase64("rcLI1XTfmXtX05zq67d1wujnUvevBu8dZ5Q5uBUi2mKndH1FZLYCKrjFaDTB/mXW1l5C74YycVLS6msY2NNJYw==");

BigInteger modulus2 = new BigInteger().FromBigEndian(param.Modulus);
```

Hope this helps others with the same problem :-)

Comment: perhaps this previous stackoverflow post can help you to see what you are doing wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570029/how-can-i-fill-in-rsaparameters-value-in-c-sharp

Comment: unfortunatelly not. I already spend this whole day on SO reading .Net RSA threads. my problem ist not that anything is not working, but that I do not understand why the product of p and q does not match the modulus.

Comment: I get different numbers than you. For example, the modulus I get from the above file is `9100595563660672087698322262735024483609782000266155222822537546670463733453350686171384417480667378838400923087358115007100900745853538273602044437940579`

Comment: how did you do that? can you give me your code lines? *confused*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my parsing of the XML parameters you provided:

```
N = 9100595563660672087698322262735024483609782000266155222822537546670463733453350686171384417480667378838400923087358115007100900745853538273602044437940579

P = 96731388413554317303099785843734797692955743043844132225634400270674214374921

Q = 94081101418218318334927154927633016498744568046568114230258529096538660255499
```

As you can verify, N does indeed equal P * Q.

You cannot use the BigInteger(byte []) constructor the way you are because it expects the byte array to be in little-endian, and because Microsoft has done things bass ackwards. Instead, reverse the order of the bytes. And finally, because the bytes arrays are supposed to be twos complement and your numbers are guaranteed to be positive you must add a zero byte to the high order byte of the array *if* the high-order byte would otherwise be greater than or equal to 128.

Comment: caluclating the last digits in head seams that you got the right numbers. now i am totally interested in getting the way you did it?

How did you parse the XML values to the numbers?

Comment: Microsoft expect the byte array going to BigInteger() to be backwards. It's just too stupid to even discuss.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg. Seems my endian check got a double fault converting back and forward **outsch**
Now I understand why everywhere everybody wrote "do not use BigInteger its crap" :)

Comment: Most of the time, you actually do operations with a BigInteger. Exporting is rare. That's why x86 processors and, well, BigInteger are little-endian.

Comment: there is nothing stupid or microsoft specific about Endianness of bytes. Some are Most significant byte first, some are Least significant byte first. It all depends on the hardware or agreements. ASN-1 integers normally are LSB, so is the intel processor. Motorola mostly is MSB first..

Comment: @LucVandenbroucke: The DER/BER encoding of ASN.1 integers is most significant byte first. This has nothing to do with internal hardware representation, this is about serializing values for external storage/transmission. Every standard I've come across formats multibyte integers as big-endian. People write integer values down in the decimal equivalent of big endian. Microsoft itself uses big-endian for some things and little endian for others. This has nothing to do with processors, this is entirely about the careless way Microsoft produced and documented APIs.

Comment: Ok. I hot wrong info on DER. But little endian is not Microsoft but Intel. Linux on x86 is little endian also.   But ok ...now Microsoft is forced to use little endian on arm processors.. which are MSB bt default.   On some smartcard I even have to use MSB it LSB depending on context...

Answer (score 6):

`BigInteger` parses arrays as signed little-endian values. `RSAParameters` uses unsigned big-endian.

So `i = new BigInteger(bytes.Reverse().Concat(new byte[]{0}).ToArray()))` should work.

Comment: This is wrong. You need to swap the substreams. `i = new BigInteger(bytes.Reverse()).ToArray().Concat(new byte[]{0}))`