# Mapping RSA Encryption Parameters from CRT (Chinese remainder theorem) to .NET format

Tags: c#, .net, c, rsa, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to implement RSA encryption/decryption using C#

I have a private key with following parameters:

`mod n`, `exponent`, `p`, `q`, `dP`, `dQ`, and `(p`<sup>`-1`</sup>`mod q)`

Above parameters are explained in [Chinese remainder algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm)

However C#.NET implementation of the RSA has different parameter set as following:

`Modulus`, `Exponent`, `P`,  `Q`, `DP`, `DQ`, `D`, `InverseQ`

When I'm trying to map the data from `CRT` to `DOTNET`, I get error `Bad Data`

For  `p`,`q`, `dP` and `dQ` the mapping is obvious but about the rest of parameters I'm not sure.

It would be great if I can get help mapping these paramters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mod n` maps to `Modulus`, `p`<sup>`-1`</sup>`mod q` maps to `InverseQ`, the encryption exponent maps to `Exponent` and the decryption exponent maps to `D`.

The encryption exponent `e` and the decryption exponent `d` are related by e*d = 1 mod (p-1)(q-1). Thus if you have one them you can easily derive the other use a few methods from the System.Numerics.BigInteger class.

```
var Pminus1 = BigInteger.Subtract(P, BigInteger.One);
var Qminus1 = BigInteger.Subtract(Q, BigInteger.One);
var Phi = BigInteger.Multiply(Pminus1, Qminus1);
var PhiMinus1 = BigInteger.Subtract(Phi, BigInteger.One);
// var D = BigInteger.ModPow(E, PhiMinus1, Phi);
```

Note that care must be taken when constructing a .NET BigInteger, especially if you are used to Java's BigInteger class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14073787/1041046) for more information.

EDIT :

As CodeInChaos points out that last line is WRONG!

WRONG! WRONG! WRONG!

I am embarrassed. In a bow to the forces of evil the BigInteger class does not have a modular inverse method nor an extended euclidean algorithm method. You can nevertheless google for 'c # extended euclidean algorithm' you can find many implementations. The extended euclidean algorithm will give you integers x and y such that 1 = e*x + phi * y. x is the inverse of e mod phi, so setting D = x mod phi is what is needed.

Comment: GregS, In my case I only have one exponent which is an prime number. should I use it as both encryption and decryption exponents? In other words assign same number to both D and Exponent?

Comment: No, the encrypt and decrypt exponents are different, although one can be derived from other when you have both the primes.

Comment: When I generate RSA key in C#, `D` is same size as Modulus (128bytes or 1024bits). As you can see in question, my data does not have D or anything named Encryption/Decryption Exponent. Is there any practical reference to calculate D from given Data. All the sample codes that I could find use an integer Modulus (2 bytes) which is not my case

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to your answer in [Why is RSAParameters Modulus not equal product of P and Q](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14073787/1041046) I assume I need to reverse the p and q before using your method. For Completeness, Could you please include that in your answer too?

Comment: I tried `D` calculation with your suggested way on a pre-generated key which didn't work. I posted it as a different question as it wasn't related to this one. Hope you can point out my mistake. Here is the  [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14229040/1041046)

Comment: Can you justify "var D = BigInteger.ModPow(E, PhiMinus1, Phi);"? I don't see why that should be the modular inverse.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Did I get it wrong? I did get it wrong! It should be phi(phi(N)) - 1.

Answer (score 2):

Extended Euclidean algorithm can be used to compute the modular inverse, in this case D will be calculated, use this link: http://www.di-mgt.com.au/euclidean.html#extendedeuclidean to get the detail,
I tested the source code in C# as below, and the result is matching,

```
public static BigInteger modinv(BigInteger u, BigInteger v)
{
   BigInteger inv, u1, u3, v1, v3, t1, t3, q;
   BigInteger iter;
   /* Step X1. Initialise */
   u1 = 1;
   u3 = u;
   v1 = 0;
   v3 = v;
   /* Remember odd/even iterations */
   iter = 1;
   /* Step X2. Loop while v3 != 0 */
   while (v3 != 0)
   {
       /* Step X3. Divide and "Subtract" */
       q = u3 / v3;
       t3 = u3 % v3;
       t1 = u1 + q * v1;
       /* Swap */
       u1 = v1; v1 = t1; u3 = v3; v3 = t3;
       iter = -iter;
   }
   /* Make sure u3 = gcd(u,v) == 1 */
   if (u3 != 1)
       return 0;   /* Error: No inverse exists */
       /* Ensure a positive result */
       if (iter < 0)
           inv = v - u1;
       else
           inv = u1;
       return inv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

D can be calculated like this:

```
    var qq = BigInteger.Multiply(phi, n);
    var qw = BigInteger.Multiply(phi, qq);
    BigInteger D = BigInteger.ModPow(e, (qw - 1), phi);
```